# Yet another directory issue (Java)

Tags: java, input

in my program I would like the user to name their project whatever they would like. So what I need is some way to have the program make a new folder called *What ever the user wants*. the way I'd like it to happen is by useing a *String* which I can put in the already existing code to make the new folder.

```
package com.AlexAdams.SimpleHTML.Program;

import java.io.File;
import com.AlexAdams.SimpleHTML.PopUps.SimpleHTMLDirctoryError;


public class MainFrameCreateMenuCreateNewProject {

public static boolean programDirctory = false;

    public MainFrameCreateMenuCreateNewProject() {

        /*"SimpleHTML" MAIN FILE DIRCTORY*/
        String simpleHTMLpath = System.getProperty("user.home") + File.separator + "Documents";
        simpleHTMLpath += File.separator + "SimpleHTML";
        File SimpleHTML = new File(simpleHTMLpath);

        if (SimpleHTML.exists()) {
            System.out.println(SimpleHTML + " Dirctory already exists");
            programDirctory = true;
        } else if (SimpleHTML.mkdirs()) {
            System.out.println(SimpleHTML + " Dirctory was created");
            programDirctory = true;
        } else {
            System.out.println(SimpleHTML + " Dirctory was not created");
            programDirctory = false;
            new SimpleHTMLDirctoryError();
        }

        if (programDirctory = true) {
            /*"SimpleHTML User Defined Project Name"*/
            String simpleHTMLprojectpath = System.getProperty("user.home") + File.separator + "SimpleHTML";
            simpleHTMLprojectpath += File.separator + ""; // Put the code for the users name of there project
            File /*String of user input from JTextField*/ = new File(simpleHTMLprojectpath);

            if (/*Code of user definedprojectname*/.exists()) {
                System.out.println(" Project name already exists");
            } else if (/*Code of user definedprojectname*/.mkdirs()) {
                System.out.println(" New project was created");
            } else {
                System.out.println(" New project could not be created");
            }
        } else if (programDirctory = false) {
            System.out.println(" Project could not be created. This may be due to the fact that there is a error with the programs main file dirctroy.");
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: So, what's your question? Have you at least tried replacing "SimpleHTML" by an argument of type String?

Comment: The `programDirctory` boolean field in your `if (programDirctory = true)` get true parameter, So never run your `else if (programDirctory = false)` code (in this case your boolean filed get false).

Answer (score 1):

First off, you have a logic error...

```
 if (programDirctory = true) {
```

Will always be `true` as you assigning `true` to `programDirctory` before the `if` statement evaluates it.

Better to use

```
 if (programDirctory) {
```

The same thing goes for `else if (programDirctory = false)`, but considering that the value is either `true` or `false`, there are only two states available, so you can shorten this to...

```
 if (programDirctory) {
     //...
 } else {
     //...
 }
```

If you want to supply a variable value, then you need to provide a parameter to your constructor...

For example...

```
public MainFrameCreateMenuCreateNewProject(String userPath) {
    /*"SimpleHTML" MAIN FILE DIRCTORY*/
    String simpleHTMLpath = System.getProperty("user.home") + File.separator + "Documents";
    simpleHTMLpath += File.separator + "SimpleHTML";
    File SimpleHTML = new File(simpleHTMLpath);

    if (SimpleHTML.exists()) {
        System.out.println(SimpleHTML + " Dirctory already exists");
        programDirctory = true;
    } else if (SimpleHTML.mkdirs()) {
        System.out.println(SimpleHTML + " Dirctory was created");
        programDirctory = true;
    } else {
        System.out.println(SimpleHTML + " Dirctory was not created");
        programDirctory = false;
        throw new IOException(SimpleHTML + " does not exist and could not be created");
    }

    if (programDirctory) {
        /*"SimpleHTML User Defined Project Name"*/
        String simpleHTMLprojectpath = simpleHTMLpath + 
            File.separator + 
            userPath; // Put the code for the users name of there project
        File userProject = new File(simpleHTMLprojectpath);

        if (userProject.exists()) {
            System.out.println(" Project name already exists");
        } else if (userProject.mkdirs()) {
            System.out.println(" New project was created");
        } else {
            System.out.println(" New project could not be created");
        }
    }
}
```

Then you would simply call it using something like...

```
new MainFrameCreateMenuCreateNewProject("MyProject");
```

But to me, this seems a bit pointless, as the class doesn't do anything.  A better solution might be to make a static method instead...

```
public class MainFrameCreateMenuCreateNewProject {

    public static void createUserFolder(String userPath) {
        boolean programDirctory = false;
        //...etc...
    }

}
```

Which would allow you to use...

```
MainFrameCreateMenuCreateNewProject.createUserFolder("MyProject");
```

The next problem is, what to do if you couldn't create the folder for some reason?  You could return a `boolean`, but that doesn't really mean much, instead, it might be better to throw a `IOException`, for example...

```
public static void createNewProjectPath(String userPath) throws IOException {
    /*"SimpleHTML" MAIN FILE DIRCTORY*/
    String simpleHTMLpath = System.getProperty("user.home") + File.separator + "Documents";
    simpleHTMLpath += File.separator + "SimpleHTML";
    File SimpleHTML = new File(simpleHTMLpath);

    if (SimpleHTML.exists()) {
        System.out.println(SimpleHTML + " Dirctory already exists");
        programDirctory = true;
    } else if (SimpleHTML.mkdirs()) {
        System.out.println(SimpleHTML + " Dirctory was created");
        programDirctory = true;
    } else {
        System.out.println(SimpleHTML + " Dirctory was not created");
        programDirctory = false;
        throw new IOException(SimpleHTML + " does not exist and could not be created");
    }

    if (programDirctory) {
        /*"SimpleHTML User Defined Project Name"*/
        String simpleHTMLprojectpath = simpleHTMLpath + 
            File.separator + 
            userPath; // Put the code for the users name of there project
        File userProject = new File(simpleHTMLprojectpath);

        if (userProject.exists()) {
            System.out.println(" Project name already exists");
        } else if (userProject.mkdirs()) {
            System.out.println(" New project was created");
        } else {
            System.out.println(" New project could not be created");
            throw new IOException(userProject + " does not exist and could not be created");
        }
    }
}
```

But, to be honest, you could probably simplify the code by doing something like...

```
public class MainFrameCreateMenuCreateNewProject {

    public static void createNewProjectPath(String userPath) throws IOException {

        createNewPath("SimpleHTML");
        createNewPath(userPath);

    }

    public static void createNewPath(String path) throws IOException {
        String fullPath = System.getProperty("user.home") + File.separator + "Documents";
        fullPath += File.separator + path;
        File filePath = new File(fullPath);

        if (!filePath.exists() && !filePath.mkdirs()) {

            throw new IOException(filePath + " does not exist and could not be created");

        }

    }

}
```

Comment: Sorry for replying so late. I've tried the longer option and the compressed code one as well and it doesn't even make the programes main directory any more...

Comment: Actually that hole class doesn't get called.. how would I make it get called thorugh a ActionLisener?

Comment: That would depend on which version of the code you are using. Pas for the second example, seen as they are static methods, you should be able to call them directly...

Comment: Thank you for still replying! How would I call the static method from an ActionListener from another class?

Comment: Like any other `static` method `MainFrameCreateMenuCreateNewProject.createNewProjectPath(userPath);`

Comment: Sorry I don't under stand how to do that I guess I never learnt how to call other classes. I've always used `new MainFrameCreateMenuCreateNewProject.createNewProjectPath()` so could you please explain how I would call it from the button actionlistener in the other class?

Comment: I just did.  A `static` method or variable doesn't rely on a class instance, so you can call it directly.  If it's `public`, you can call it from anywhere, if it's `protected`, you can only call it where the calling class is within the same package...

Comment: Yes okay I'm calling it but I'm getting a red underline error under `.createNewProject(userPath)` the userpath part.

Comment: You need to supply some `String` value as the parameter, I just used a variable called `userPath`, feel free to get creative ;)

Answer (score 0):

Simply asking, is this what you want?

```
public MainFrameCreateMenuCreateNewProject(String ProjectName) {

        /*"SimpleHTML" MAIN FILE DIRCTORY*/
        String simpleHTMLpath = System.getProperty("user.home") + File.separator + "Documents";
        simpleHTMLpath += File.separator + ProjectName;
        File SimpleHTML = new File(simpleHTMLpath);

        if (SimpleHTML.exists()) {
            System.out.println(SimpleHTML + " Dirctory already exists");
            programDirctory = true;
        } else if (SimpleHTML.mkdirs()) {
            System.out.println(SimpleHTML + " Dirctory was created");
            programDirctory = true;
        } else {
            System.out.println(SimpleHTML + " Dirctory was not created");
            programDirctory = false;
            throw new SimpleHTMLDirctoryException("Error in creating directory");
        }

        if (programDirctory) {
            /*"SimpleHTML User Defined Project Name"*/
            String simpleHTMLprojectpath = System.getProperty("user.home") + File.separator + ProjectName;
            simpleHTMLprojectpath += File.separator + ProjectName; // Put the code for the users name of there project
            File /*String of user input from JTextField*/ file = new File(simpleHTMLprojectpath);

            if (file.exists()) {
                System.out.println(" Project name already exists");
            } else if (file.mkdirs()) {
                System.out.println(" New project was created");
            } else {
                System.out.println("New project could not be created");
            }
        } else {
            System.out.println(" Project could not be created. This may be due to the fact that there is a error with the programs main file dirctroy.");
        }
    }
```

If so, can't you just replace the String with a variable, and pass it as the argument in the constructor?